# React componentWillMount() and render() never gets called

Tags: reactjs, render

I am trying to write a HOC in react to protect path and somehow except for the constructor, none of the function in the class was called. Here's what I have for the code (this.props.userProfile is another function that would return information about the user. The function works perfectly fine with other components so I don't think it would contribute to the problem)

```
import React from 'react';
class AuthorizedHOC extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, allowedRoles) {
    super(props);
    console.log('in authorizedHOC');
    this.state = {'role':false};
    this.checkAuthorization = this.checkAuthorization.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    this.checkAuthorization();
    console.log('in component will mount');
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    this.checkAuthorization();
    console.log('in next props will mount');
  }

  checkAuthorization(){
    console.log('checkAuthorization');
    let userProfile = this.props.userProfile;
    for (let role in allowedRoles){
        if (userProfile.roles.includes(role)){
            console.log("have access");
            this.state.role = true;
        }
    }
    console.log('in side checkAuthorization');
  }

  render() {
    console.log('in render');
    return (<div>
    {this.state.role ? <WrappedComponent {...this.props}/> : <p>not 
    allowed</p>}
    </div>);
  }
}
export default AuthorizedHOC;
```

Comment: I've never seen a constructor that took anything besides `props`. Where does `allowedRoles` come from? Can it be passed as a prop, and accessed by `this.props.allowedRoles` ?

Comment: I was thinking about passing allowedRoles in as HOC acts as a function? I can try to look into this to see if allowedRoles was the issue, but it makes sense that it may be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

the `componentWillMount()` is deprecced and it will be or has been removed , you should use `UNSAFE_componentWillMount()` instead.

But i wouldn't advice you to use this life cycle method because if you do an API async  call in this method , the component will render before the call finish

Comment: would that apply to componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) as well? it didn't fix it :(

Comment: @nguyli03  yes you need to use the prefix UNSAFE for those methode

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you have now doesn't look quite correct. HOCs are meant to be written as functions which accept other components, compose them, then return a new component, [as described in the guide here](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html#use-hocs-for-cross-cutting-concerns). There are a few other issues as well.

1. In regards to the `this.state.role = true;` line, the state's not meant to be mutated directly, only to be updated through `this.setState({ ... })` as to properly tell react to perform a new render with the new state.
2. The `componentWill*` functions have been deprecated, and using them is unsafe for async rendering. [See this blog post for details.](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html) Here, instead of `componentWillMount`, you should use `componentDidMount`.
3. Instead of using `componentWillReceiveProps`, it looks like you could straight-forwardly perform your calculations in render instead. It's considered an anti-pattern to manually sync state to props like this.

Since you can perform calculations directly based off of props, state actually becomes unnecessary.

```
import React from "react"

function withAuthorization(allowedRoles, WrappedComponent) {
  return class AuthorizedHOC extends React.Component {
    render() {
      const { userProfile } = this.props
      let authorized
      for (let role in allowedRoles) {
        if (userProfile.roles.includes(role)) {
          authorized = true
        }
      }

      return <div>{authorized ? <WrappedComponent {...this.props} /> : <p>not allowed</p>}</div>
    }
  }
}

export default withAuthorization

// usage
function SecretPage() {
  return <div>only shows when authorized</div>
}

const SecretPageWithAuth = withAuthorization(["allowed", "roles", "here"], SecretPage)

// example usage w/ react router
<Route path='/test' component={SecretPageWithAuth} />
```

You could probably make the `AuthorizedHOC` component into a stateless one, and the render function could probably be made cleaner as well. I wanted to write it in a way that resembles the original code more closely.

Comment: so to pass in a component with route, it would be <Route path="/test" component={withAuthorization(['admin'],test} />, is that correct? Because I was trying that out before I made HOC as an entire class, it kept telling me that this.props is undefined. I also added in function constructor(props)

Comment: Firstly, when you use the HOC, you want to make the new component outside of render: `const SecretPage = withAuthorization(...)` then use _that_ in your routes: `<Route path='/test' component={SecretPage} />`.

Comment: Second, when you don't need to add state to your component, you can leave off the constructor, and JS will sort of add the `constructor(props) { super(props) }` automatically so you don't have to do so yourself.

Comment: so it would be SecretPage = withAuthorization(['admin'], test)? what does props => (<div>only shows when authorized</div>) would do?

Comment: That's just a [stateless component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#functional-and-class-components) being passed in as the second parameter for `WrappedComponent`. I'll edit my post to make that clearer.

Comment: Thank you. I understand now. I get this.props is undefined but it maybe because of something else.